# Insert into 3 tables at a time using stored procedures

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

How do I insert into multiple tables in a stored procedure? For example, I have a form, when I submit this form values, it should be inserted into 3 tables in a Oracle DB. I have written a stored procedure,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_through_procedure(
p_cid IN table1.cid%TYPE,
p_uid IN table1.UID%TYPE,
p_chlnno     IN table1.chlnno%TYPE,
p_cdate      IN table1.cdate%TYPE,
p_createdby  IN table1.createdby%TYPE,
p_createdon  IN table1.createdon%TYPE,
p_finyearid  IN table1.finyearid%TYPE,
p_cstatus    IN table1.cstatus%TYPE,
p_aid        IN table2.applid%TYPE,
p_name       IN table2.aname%TYPE,
p_addr       IN table2.aaddress%TYPE,
p_email      IN table2.aemail%TYPE,
p_mobile     IN table2.mobileno%TYPE,
p_contact    IN table2.contactno%TYPE,
p_cdid       IN cm_challan_details.cdid%TYPE,
p_sid        IN table3.sid%TYPE,
p_year       IN table3.year%TYPE,
p_month      IN table3.month%TYPE,
p_val1       IN table3.val1%TYPE,
p_val2       IN table3.val2%TYPE,
p_val3       IN table3.val3%TYPE,
p_totalval   IN table3.total%TYPE) AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1(cid, UID, chlnno, cdate, createdby, createdon, finyearid, cstatus) VALUES (1, 1, 'chln01', p_challandate, p_createdby, to_date('02 / 02 / 2015','dd/mm/yyyy'), 1, 1);    
  INSERT INTO table2(cid, aid, aname, aaddress, aemail, mobileno, contactno) VALUES (1, 1, 'usha', p_addr, p_email, p_mobile, p_contact);    
  INSERT INTO table3(cdid, cid, sid, year, month, fee, cess, penalty, total) VALUES (101, 1, 1, p_year, p_month, 10.25, 0.25, 0.1, 10.61);    
  COMMIT;
END insert_through_procedure;
```

And I am testing this stored procedure by providing values with in insert statement, I have no errors but when I compile and execute I get error,

```
Connecting to the database u_tax.
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("PTIS_CHECKLIST"."table1"."CREATEDON")
ORA-06512: at "PTIS_CHECKLIST.INSERT_THROUGH_PROCEDURE", line 28
ORA-06512: at line 48
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database u_tax.
```

Thank you. now I got new error..

```
Procedure PTIS_CHECKLIST.table3@u_tax
Error(28,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(28,166): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
Error(29,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(30,16): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

New error updated,

```
Connecting to the database u_tax.
ORA-00001: unique constraint (PTIS_CHECKLIST.table1_PK) violated
ORA-06512: at "PTIS_CHECKLIST.insert_through_procedure", line 28
ORA-06512: at line 48
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database u_tax.
```

Where did I go wrong....? Can anyone help me to solve the problem please....

Comment: Can ou please format your code?

Comment: _ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("PTIS_CHECKLIST"."table1"."CREATEDON")
ORA-06512: at "PTIS_CHECKLIST.INSERT_THROUGH_PROCEDURE", line 28_

Comment: I have formatteed code.. Can u please help me.... @Jens

Comment: @Jens Thank you.. Date error has ben resolved.. Now i got different error. I have updated the error part above, can u help me..

Comment: @user4627344, you have multiple issues. See my answer, I have pointed out a few.

Comment: @Jens. can you help me in the updated error..

Comment: @user4627344 see my updated answer. Try the `to_date` function.

Comment: Show your updated code as well. And did you follow my suggestions? I have given you the correct insert statement.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B. I have updated my code as well..

Comment: That is not what I suggested. See my answer. Use `to_date('10/03/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')`. I gave a complete query, how difficult is it to copy paste it and check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> p_createdon  IN table1.createdon%TYPE,
>
> 10 / 03 / 2015

What is `10 / 03 / 2015`? Is it a **DATE** or a **STRING**? Oracle has no idea unless you explicitly tell it. You cannot insert the value `10 / 03 / 2015` like that. First you need to tell us the data type of the column `createdon`. If you are dealing with DATE then the **data type must be a DATE**.

Assuming the data type is a DATE. You need to insert using **TO_DATE** and proper format mask to convert the literal into date. Use

```
to_date('10/03/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Your insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO cm_challan_main 
   (cid, UID, chlnno, cdate, createdby, createdon, finyearid, cstatus)
 VALUES 
(1, 1, chln01, p_challandate, p_createdby, to_date('10/03/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1, 1);
```

> ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Another issue is with the column name used in the insert statement instead of a value. You must **enclose the string literals within single-quotation marks**.

> chln01
>
> usha

You must insert the above string as:

`'chln01'` and `'usha'`.

Comment: kumar. Thank you.. I resolved these 2 errors, but still I am getting Error(28,3) and (28, 166)..

Comment: So you tell me what is at those line numbers? Without knowing the table structures, nobody can do a wild guess about the error cause. And please mark it as answered if it has helped you.

Comment: I have updated with updated line numbers error. Your answer is helping me a lot.. Thank you..

Comment: You did not do what I suggested. You didn't even read my answer it seems. `'02 / 02 / 2015'` is wrong. you must use `to_date('10/03/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')`. How difficult is it to simply copy paste my query from the answer.

Comment: Sorry, While updating code i have done mistake, but I have executed as suggested by you and i have read your answer suggested by you.... Now you can see i have updated it correctly.

Comment: The error is clear `ORA-00001: unique constraint (PTIS_CHECKLIST.table1_PK) violated` you are inserting duplicate values into the table. Please mark the answer as answered.

Comment: Can i use select statement in in same procedure. I want to confirm user that data has been inserted successfully with his id(Here I have to display chlnno). After insert statements can i use select statement..

Comment: You could do `select chlnno into variable from table where id = input_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Copied from my comment:

You have to add double quotes arround 10 / 03 / 2015 if it is a date type. If you do not add the quotes oracle will divide the values.

Or you can use `to_date()` function to convert it explicitly to a date.

```
TO_DATE( '10/03/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```